# Lodash _.set creates empty object keys

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have the following line:

```
_.set(state, `timeTable.${new Date().getMonth()}.${new Date().getDate()}.name`, someNameValue);
```

And if today's date is for example: **8 Aug (Month: 8, Day:8)**
This will set the `state object` such as:

```
const state = {
  timeTable: {
    0: null,
    1: null,
    ...
    8: {
      0: null,
      1: null,
      ...
      8: {
        name: someNameValue,
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Why does it do this ? Or how can I create only the keys that I need without creating those `null objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the state as an Object before calling this method. Using integer/numeric index will force-fill all the previous indexes as null. Instead, I would suggest you use String as a key.

```
_.set(state, `timeTable.month_${new Date().getMonth()}.date_${new Date().getDate()}.name`, someNameValue);
```

And make sure you are not calling this set method when the data is empty. For example, if you don't have data for say, August 6, then this line should not execute for August 6. If you are using this in a loop, you should check this.